# Android - UI UX of a VERY BIG array for auto-completion

Tags: android, arrays, user-interface, user-experience

I would like some guidance on designing a layout that caters to UI (saddle, stirrups and reins) and UX (overall ride). (See here for [horse ride analogy](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/06/ui-vs-ux-whats-the-difference/)).

I want users to select their location by typing the first few characters. Suppose, the locations are all the capital cities of all countries. One school of thought may suggest a drill-down approach for the location to be selected. For example, start with a geography (USA, LA, EMEA, APAC, etc.), then select a country from that geography.

The other suggestion would be to load up all the capital cities into an array and feed it to the auto-complete view.

Personally, I prefer the latter from a UX perspective. A person who wants to enter his/her location *already knows what is to be selected*. He/she doesn't need navigation. On the other hand, consider your tax filing procedure. A guided navigation around nature of income, saving or exemptions can result in a truly satisfying UX, because the user wouldn't know in advance what tax code or exemption code, etc. needs to be selected.

The counter point to my preference is from a UI perspective. The larger the size of array (fed to the auto-complete view), the bigger the size of 'drop-down' because the first few characters will match way too many. This will hurt the UX. I did see an option for the maximum number of lines to be shown - `android:maxLines`. See below for example.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
android:maxLines="5"
android:text="AutoCompleteTextView" />
```

Can this be used so that, upon typing text into the auto-complete view, doesn't engulf the layout ?

Another counter-point - also from UI perspective - is performance. With a string array of say around 10,000+ entries, would the application go into a ANR ? What rule may one follow to determine an upper limit for the array entries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't look for a rule. I'd just make sure to test it with an old device.

Don't try to optimize it prematurely.

If you do need to optimize it, you can always divide your array by 26, and use a different array for each letter of the alphabet. And you can keep on dividing it that way until the performance becomes acceptable to you.

Comment: I like the "divide the array by 26" part. Could you please describe in Android terms? Is it like setting the string array dynamically based on first character entered?

Comment: Take a look at this example. https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android This example actually goes out on the web to fetch its data each time a character is typed, which is more than what you need to do).

Comment: O.k. I will explore. Thanks Stephan!

Comment: Yes, got it working with some mock data ! Just one more question. How do I ensure that the auto-complete is triggered only when a minimum of 3 characters are entered ?